# StAX well-formedness check of XML

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, stax, well-formed

I am checking an XML document for well formedness (only syntax check). I am not validating against any schema.
I need to do this using StAX:

I do know that I have to parse the file, but how do I implement the check?

```
XMLInputFactory factory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance(); 
File f = new File(uploadfileName);
FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(f); 
//Instantiate a reader parsing:
XMLStreamReader reader=factory.createXMLStreamReader(inputStream);

        while(reader.hasNext()){
            //check to be implemented??
            reader.next();
        }
```

Comment: You're done. By reading all events, the XML has been processed in full, so you know there are no XML syntax errors. If there had been, an exception would have been thrown. --- FYI: When I say done, I mean that you'll be done when you close the `inputStream`, preferably using try-with-resources.

Comment: So if i want to explicitly add my own error message, do I use a try- catch block?

Comment: if you have to make sure the well-formed-ness of XML before processing, add an empty pass at the beginning...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [@Andreas commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38255981/stax-validation-of-xml/38257285#comment63933015_38255981), well-formedness will be indicated by the lack of any exception being thrown in the course of consuming all parsing events.

Specifically, [`XMLStreamReader.next()`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/1.5/api/javax/xml/stream/XMLStreamReader.html#next()) will throw a [`XMLStreamException`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/1.5/api/javax/xml/stream/XMLStreamException.html) for any well-formedness errors encountered in the XML being parsed.  If parsing progresses to where [`XMLStreamReader.hasNext()`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/1.5/api/javax/xml/stream/XMLStreamReader.html#hasNext()) returns `false` and terminates your `while` loop without having triggered any `XMLStreamExceptions`, you can be sure that the XML is well-formed.